# Select Command With different where condition in same table which give result in two parreller column

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want these result in parallel column combine
For login column

```
select [Discrepant Reason],count([Discrepant Reason]) as "Login" 
from   Book1 
where ( Remarks<>'Sales Reject' and MONTH([Application Receipt date])=7) 
group by [Discrepant Reason]
```

Fro sales reject column

```
select [Discrepant Reason],count([Discrepant Reason]) as "Sales reject" 
from   Book1 
where ( Remarks='Sales Reject' and MONTH([Application Receipt date])=7)
group by [Discrepant Reason]
```

========================================================================

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use conditional aggregation

```
select [Discrepant Reason],
sum(case when Remarks='Sales Reject' and MONTH([Application Receipt date])=7 then 1 else 0 end) Login,
sum(case when Remarks<>'Sales Reject' and MONTH([Application Receipt date])=7 then 1 else 0 end) Sales_reject from tble
group by [Discrepant Reason]
```

Comment: Hi Zaynul Abadin Tuhin : big thanks to you. you solved my problem..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need

```
select [Discrepant Reason],
  sum(case when Remarks='Sales Reject' then 1 else 0 end) Login,
  sum(case when Remarks<>'Sales Reject' then 1 else 0 end) Sales_reject 
from Book1 
where MONTH([Application Receipt date])=7
group by [Discrepant Reason]
```